# Google Map markers and JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, marker

I have a database which stores the position of markers previously added on the Google Map (Latitude/Longitude). What I want to do now, it's to create a function which takes a JSON object as a parameter, containing those markers position and add automatically the markers in the map. I start to get the markers from my database and try to loop on the JSON object which looks like this:

```
 {"markers":"\"[{\\\"k\\\":48.80686346108517,\\\"B\\\":1.494140625},{\\\"k\\\":50.28933925329177,\\\"B\\\":14.326171875},{\\\"k\\\":43.70759350405294,\\\"B\\\":21.357421875},{\\\"k\\\":30.977609093348686,\\\"B\\\":11.337890625},{\\\"k\\\":40.58058466412761,\\\"B\\\":-0.87890625},{\\\"k\\\":48.45835188280866,\\\"B\\\":1.318359375}]\""}
```

Here is the current state of my code:

```
 //Create a new set of markers based on received position.
 function createMarkerBasedOnFetchedPosition(fetchedMarkersPosition)
 {
   var jsonData = JSON.parse(fetchedMarkersPosition);
   alert(fetchedMarkersPosition);
   map.addMarker({
                  lat: ? //Fetched from the JSON object parsing.
                  lng: ? //Fetched from the JSON object parsing.
                  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
 });
```

Can anyone please help me to build this, I don't know yet how to deal with a JSON object to retrieve the Latitude/Longitude. I'm looking for a JavaScript solution only. Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you tried anything? what is your current code

Comment: I never down voted, and see my answer below of how to loop through your data, you question is kind of unclear though, are you struggling to loop through your markers or are you struggling getting the data from your database?

Answer (score 1):

From your current code you would then need to loop through the markers with a for loop like so and add a marker to the map:

```
var data = '{"markers":[{"k":48.80686346108517,"B":1.494140625},{"k":50.28933925329177,"B":14.326171875},{"k":43.70759350405294,"B":21.357421875},{"k":30.977609093348686,"B":11.337890625},{"k":40.58058466412761,"B":-0.87890625},{"k":48.45835188280866,"B":1.318359375}]}';

function createMarkerBasedOnFetchedPosition(fetchedMarkersPosition)
{
   var jsonData = JSON.parse(fetchedMarkersPosition);
   for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.markers.length; i++) {
        map.addMarker({
            lat: jsonData.markers[i].k,
            lng: jsonData.markers[i].b,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
    }
}

createMarkerBasedOnFetchedPosition(data);
```

Comment: that is because your json string is being escaped and theres a few errors inside, it should look more along the lines of `{"markers":[{"k":48.80686346108517,"B":1.494140625},{"k":50.28933925329177,"B":14.326171875},{"k":43.70759350405294,"B":21.357421875},{"k":30.977609093348686,"B":11.337890625},{"k":40.58058466412761,"B":-0.87890625},{"k":48.45835188280866,"B":1.318359375}]}`